# Text features encoding rule

Tags: text, vowpalwabbit

I would like to use VW to train on these data:

-1 | word1 word2

1 | word1 word3 word1

... etc

As you can see, "word1" is repeated twice in the second example.

The VW documentation says the default behavior of VW is to automatically add ":1" to each token, e.g for the first example:

-1 | word1:1 word2:1

My question is: what do I have to do in the second example ?

- Option #1: transform it as follow:

1 | word1:2 word3

- Option #2: leave it "as is":

1 | word1 word3 word1

(in this case, I think that some collisions will occur)

Answer (score 0):

I just started using VW yesterday, so I could be totally mixed up, but I had the same question and I did some tests.  When it makes predictions it doesn't seem to matter whether you use "word:2" or "word word".  But, when training it **does** seem to matter.  I created two small training data files, train1 and train2, that differed only in using "word:2" vs "word word" and trained like this:

```
vw -d train1 -f predictor1.vw --loss_function hinge
vw -d train2 -f predictor2.vw --loss_function hinge
```

Then I looked at predictions for both data sets based on training from train1:

```
vw -d train1 -t -i predictor1.vw -p out ; cat out
vw -d train2 -t -i predictor1.vw -p out ; cat out
```

and they were the same.  Doing the same thing with predictor2.vw gave different results, but the same different results for both train1 and train2.

As an additional test, I created train3, which contained the word only once (not doubled in any way), just to see if the results would match either train1 or train2 to see if I could establish that one of them wasn't getting the word doubled.  It didn't match either one.  predictor3.vw gave predictions for train1 and train2 that were the same as each other, but not the same as the predictions from predictor1.vw or predictor2.vw.

This really doesn't make sense to me, unless there is some random aspect of the training (e.g. a seed) that is somehow linked to the input text before it is parsed.